¿Cuál es el tiempo máximo de ejecución por día del código appscript en cuentas gratuitas o de pago de workspace?
Mi pregunta no tiene que ver con el tiempo de ejecución máximo para una función, sino de ejecución de diversos scripts dentro de la misma cuenta.
En las cuotas dadas por Google (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=es-419) no aparece esa información. ChatGPT me dio el dato de que eran 90 minutos para las cuentas gratuitas y hasta 6 horas para las cuentas de pago, pero no pude corroborar esa información en ningún lado. Agradezco información

Dado que en realidad parece no estar documentado, puede ser que el límite no exista. Yo en todo caso, no le creería a GPT. ¿Has intentado preguntarle al soporte de Google?

No se entiende a qué te refieres con tiempo máximo de ejecución por día ni con ... ejecución de diversos scripts dentro de la misma cuenta. En el enlace aparece un uso llamado Tiempo total de ejecución de activadores, el cual es efectivamente de 90 minutos / días en cuentas gratuitas y de 6 horas / día en cuentas Workspace. Si no estamos hablando de Tiempo total de ejecución de activadores en tu caso, explícanos de qué estamos hablando, teniendo en cuenta que desde una función llamada mediante un activador, puedes llamar a todas las funciones que quieras.

No hay límite de execución total por día para funciones de Google Apps Script que son llamadas por

Un elemento de un menú personalizado
Una imagen a la que se asigando la función
Activadores simples
Diálogos, barra lateral o aplicaciones web usando el servicio HTML (google.scrpt.run).
Desde el editor de scripts
Usando el comando run de Google Apps Script API.

Esta ausencia de límite es tanto para cuentas gratuitas como para cuentas "premium" (Google Worskpace).
En relación a ChatGPT es bien conocido que no es confiable. En gran medida depende del "prompt", de la base de información a la que tiene acceso, al entrenamiento. Es conocido que en casos en los que no "encuentra una respuesta" la inventa. A esto se le conoce como alucinación de inteligencia artificial. Debido a esto no es recomendable usarlo en temas que uno desconoce, en particular si no tiene tiempo o recursos para verificar la respuesta provista por ChatGPT.
Referencia

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quotas

